# Изменение реестра привело к ошибке

Tags: windows, реестр, recovery

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage

Изменил в данной ветке реестра значение OEMCP на 65001. Теперь комп не может загрузиться и отправляет меня в recovery. Какое там было до этого значение не помню.

<strike>Руки бы мне за это поотрубать, лезу туда, куда не стоит.</strike>

Хотел изменить стандартную кодировку в командной строке. Как видите, не вышло.

Как можно решить данный вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего тут поможет только загрузка с ERD той версии которой версия виндуса. Или как вариант - загрузиться с установочной болванки винды и зайти в режим восстановления. Если всё сделать правильно - будет доступен для редактирования реестр именно твоей машины.